# How to remove unwanted characters when running command in terminal

Tags: shell, zsh, gnome-terminal, konsole

I'm using zsh with oh-my-zsh as default shell. When I run a command in guake / gnome-terminal / konsole, a string with format (special-char|command-name|%) appears as the first line of output in console. I remember that I ran `print -Pn "\e]2;$2:q\a"` in console and got this problem after that.

How can I fix this case?

[image: Terminal]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Close and reopen your shell. A similiar thing happens with PuTTy if you accidentally *cat* a binary.

Comment: I have tried to close and reopen shell even I have removed and reinstalled zsh and oh-my-zsh but the problem is still here.

Comment: What does your PROMPT variable say? It probably has something weird in it if this persists across closing the shell. This guy had a good reference: http://www.nparikh.org/unix/prompt.php and so did this guy: http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/02/my-extravagant-zsh-prompt/